# How to make horizontal scrolling with custom stacked cells SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am attempting to make a chart with multiple stacked bars that a user can horizontally scroll through that looks something like this:
[image]

To make the green gradient bars I using a `VStack` then nesting that in `ForEach` and that in a `LazyHStack` so users can scroll.  It seems that is all that it takes to overload the system however!

I've provided enough code to recreate the issue below.
It should produce: `Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI, line 0`

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  LazyHTest
//
//  Created by Scott Lydon on 4/22/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var strings: [String] = [
        "Hello",
        "How are you",
        "sdflkjl;kj",
        "sdlfkj",
        "sdlfkj",
        "lkj"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack {
            ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { str in
                VStack {
                    Text("kjkj")
                    Text("kjkjk")
                    Text("Llkjlkj")
                    Text("LKJLKJ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply surround it with a scrollView and set a .horizontal modifier. Then loop per view. So you'd have another loop inside of your VStack for each bar. Essentially a double loop. Make sure to also use a LazyVStack

Comment: adding 'indices' next to the 'string' will fix the error, like this 'ForEach(strings.indices, id: \.self)'

Comment: @Seungjun That worked. If you feel up to posting an answered I would approve it.

Comment: @ScottyBlades glad I helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding 'indices' next to the 'string' will fix the error, like `ForEach(strings.indices, id: \.self)`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var strings: [String] = [
        "Hello",
        "How are you",
        "sdflkjl;kj",
        "sdlfkj",
        "sdlfkj",
        "lkj"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack {
            ForEach(strings.indices, id: \.self) { str in
                VStack {
                    Text("kjkj")
                    Text("kjkjk")
                    Text("Llkjlkj")
                    Text("LKJLKJ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```